# Raspberry 3B+ booting from SSD into emergency mode

Tags: pi-3b+, boot-issues

I have a s Raspberry Pi 3B+ acting as a borg backup server. To make it more reliable I would like to switch from a SD card to booting from SSD.

I have been using rpi-clone to migrate the SD card content over to the SSD.

After running rpi-clone cmdline.txt was the following:

```
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=7b74bd9b-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles cfg80211.ieee80211_regdom=DE
```

Based on the blkid output

```
$ sudo blkid 
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="bootfs" LABEL="bootfs" UUID="EF6E-C078" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="7b74bd9b-01"
/dev/mmcblk0p2: LABEL="rootfs" UUID="4aa56689-dcb4-4759-90e6-179beae559ac" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="7b74bd9b-02"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="rootfs" UUID="4aa56689-dcb4-4759-90e6-179beae559ac" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="f2ec208d-02"
/dev/sda1: LABEL_FATBOOT="bootfs" LABEL="bootfs" UUID="EF6E-C078" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="f2ec208d-01"
```

I changed this to

```
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=f2ec208d-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles cfg80211.ieee80211_regdom=DE
```

This resulted in the Pi booting into emergency after the system had a "Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2dpartuuid-f2ec208d\x

/etc/fstab looks as follows:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=f2ec208d-01  /boot/firmware  vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=f2ec208d-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
```

Output of sfdisk:

```
Disk /dev/sdk: 976.56 GiB, 1048576000000 bytes, 2048000000 sectors
Disk model: SSD             
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf2ec208d

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdk1          8192  1056767  1048576  512M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdk2       1056768 30318591 29261824   14G 83 Linux
```

(command run on a different machine - therefore it's sdk and not sda :))

I would appreciate any help with troubleshooting this.

Comment: I take it you are using a USB-SSD cable/enclosure - what chipset does it use? (`lsusb` will help here)

Comment: It's a ` > Bus 005 Device 012: ID 048d:1234 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. Chipsbank CBM2199 Flash Drive`

Comment: Oh ... is that an SSD? Looks like a thumb drive - what capacity is it supposed to be?

Comment: The case claims that it is a SSD and this seems to be in line with the sfdisk output